# Make a html unordered list from javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm trying to create a unordered list from a javascript array, here is my code:

```
var names = [];
var nameList = "";

function submit()
{
var name = document.getElementById("enter");
var theName = name.value;
names.push(theName);
nameList += "<li>" + names + "</li>";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nameList;
}


<input id="enter" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Enter name" onclick="submit()">
<br>
<br>
<div id="name"></div>
```

For example, if I post 2 names, *Name1* and *Name2* my list looks like this:

```
•Name1

•Name1,Name2
```

I want it to look like this:

```
•Name1
•Name2
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use a custom function with name "submit" inside an inline event handler. As soon as you put the elements inside a form, `submit` will refer to the submit method of the `<form>` element. Also, your `div` element should be a `ul` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function submit()
{
  var name = document.getElementById("enter");
  var theName = name.value;
  names.push(theName);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "";
  for (var I = 0; I < names.length; I++)
  {
       nameList = "<li>" + names[I] + "</li>";
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += nameList;
  }
}
```

You are using an array, when you print an array JavaScript will show all the entries of the array separated by commas. You need to iterate over the array to make it work. However you can optimize this:

```js
var names = [];


function displayUserName()
{
  var theName = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  if (theName == "" || theName.length == 0)
  {
     return false; //stop the function since the value is empty.
  }
  names.push(theName);
  document.getElementById("name").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>"+names[names.length-1]+"</li>";
}
```

```html
<input id="enter" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Enter name" onclick="displayUserName()">
<br>
<br>
<div id="name"><ul></ul></div>
```

In this example the HTML is syntactically correct by using the `UL` (or unordered list) container to which the `li`s (list items) are added.

```
document.getElementById("name").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>"+names[names.length-1]+"</li>";
```

This line selects the div with the name: `name` and its first child (the `ul`). It then appends the `LI` to the list.

As @FelixKling said: avoid using reserved or ambiguous names.

Comment: No explanation is already bad, but this one actually produces incorrect results.

Comment: You should probably explain what problem(s) your code solves, and how. Code, by itself, is rarely useful as a teaching aid (and answering questions does, however tenuously, constitute 'teaching').

Comment: @FelixKling overlooked the `+=` it's gone now.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, now I can make it pretty with css. :)

Answer (score 9):

If you look at your code, you are only creating one `li` with all your `names` as the content. What you want to do is loop over your `names` and create a separate `li` for each, right?

Change:

```
nameList += "<li>" + names + "</li>";
```

to:

```
nameList = "";
for (var i = 0, name; name = names[i]; i++) {
  nameList += "<li>" + name + "</li>";
}
```

---

If you are interested in some better practices, you can check out a rewrite of your logic here: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/ccyo77ep/

Comment: Note that the loop won't handle "empty" names very well. But such validation logic is for the OP to implement.

Comment: If I do this it looks a bit better, but now I still get the previous results in another list item, if I now enter Name2 it's not the second but the third list item and Name1 is the first and second list item.

Comment: @marceljager Yes, you have `nameList` as a variable outside the `submit` closure, so it's always appending the same items. I've updated my answer so that with each submit call, `nameList` blanks itself out. That should do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>

    <label for="new-product">Add Product</label><br /><br /><input id="new-product" type="text"><br /><br /><button>Add</button>

</div>

<div>
  <ul id="products">
  </ul>
  <p id="count"></p>
</div>
```

```
  var products = [];
  var productInput = document.getElementById("new-product");

  var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  var productListHtml = "";
  var abc = 0;

  addButton.addEventListener("click", addProduct);

  function addProduct() {
      products.push(productInput.value);

      productList();


  }

  function productList() {                    
          productListHtml += "<li>" + products[abc]    + "</li>";
          document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = productListHtml;
          abc++;    
      }
```