# How to populate multiple JavaScript arrays of objects to HTMLDOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, data-structures, append

I am having difficulty to get all the array of objects and display it into HTML lists. Can anyone help me, please. The below is my HTML and JavaScript code. Looking forward to your help.

```js
const allData = [{
    date: '2nd',
    venue: 'venue1',
    location: 'location1',
  },
  {
    date: '3rd',
    venue: 'venue2',
    location: 'location2',
  },
  {
    date: '4th',
    venue: 'venue3',
    location: 'location3',
  }
]

allData.forEach(data => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.targets')].forEach(list => {
    list.innerHTML = `
<h5 >DATE</h5>
<h4 >${data.date}</h4>
<h5 >VENUE</h5>
<h4 >${data.venue}</h4>
<h5 >LOCATION</h5>
<h4 >${data.location}</h4>
<Button >BUY TICKETS</Button>
`;
  })
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="targets"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is only one `li` in your HTML, so you just overwrite the innerHTML on each iteration. Instead you need to create a new `li` for each element in your array and add it to your `ul`

Comment: can you please show me how to fix this.

Comment: see: [Create a <ul> and fill it based on a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array) and [Make a html unordered list from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677745/make-a-html-unordered-list-from-javascript-array/28677901)

Comment: @user3718511 ... From all the provided approaches, are there any questions left?

Comment: @user3718511 ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the order of for loops execution and append each string to the previous it works!

```js
const allData = [{
    date: '2nd',
    venue: 'venue1',
    location: 'location1',

  },

  {
    date: '3rd',
    venue: 'venue2',
    location: 'location2',

  },

  {
    date: '4th',
    venue: 'venue3',
    location: 'location3',

  },
];


const list = document.querySelector('.target')
let innerHTML = '';
allData.forEach(data => {
  innerHTML += `
    <li>
        <h5 class = "shows__date">DATE</h5>
        <h4 class = "shows__calander">${data.date}</h4>
        <h5 class = "shows__venue-title">VENUE</h5>
        <h4 class = "shows__venue">${data.venue}</h4>
        <h5 class = "shows__location-title">LOCATION</h5>
        <h4 class = "shows__location">${data.location}</h4>
        <Button Class = "shows__btn">BUY TICKETS</Button>
        </li>
        `;
});

list.innerHTML = innerHTML;
```

```html
<ul class="target">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to loop for `class='targets'` because you only have one **li** in your `html` code. It might be better to just get the **ul** element and then loop `allData` variable, then change the **ul** `innerHTML` on each loop.

HTML Code

```
<ul></ul>
```

JS Code:

```
const allData= [
{
   date:  '2nd',
   venue: 'venue1',
   location: 'location1',

},

{
    date:  '3rd',
    venue: 'venue2',
    location: 'location2',
    
 },

 {
    date:  '4th',
    venue: 'venue3',
    location: 'location3',
    
 },
]

let ul = document.querySelector('ul')
let listContent = ''
allData.forEach(data=>{
        listContent = listContent +
          `                  
        <li>
            <h5 >DATE</h5>
            <h4 >${data.date}</h4>
            <h5 >VENUE</h5>
            <h4 >${data.venue}</h4>
            <h5 >LOCATION</h5>
            <h4 >${data.location}</h4>
            <Button >BUY TICKETS</Button>
        </li>
        `;
   });

   ul.innerHTML = listContent
```

Edited based on [pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) comment

Comment: as i noted earlier on @narenmurali's answer, updating the innerHTML of an active element on each iteration isn't great. Instead generate all the elements to be added and then make a single change after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The OP provides a basic list structure by the *"naked"* `<ul/>` / `<li/>`
markup.

Thus, there is only a sole `<li class="targets"></li>` element which can be accessed with a query like `'.targets'`. Which means, the OP always writes to one and the same element which shows the expected result of a list which features just one element with the data-array's last item-data.

But the `<li/>` element can be used as a blueprint for creating other list-item elements via [`<node>.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) which all will be `<li class="targets"></li>`-alike.

Now one can assign the correct data-item related html content to each newly created list-item clone which also gets [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)ed to its parent list-element ...

```js
const allData = [{
  date: '2nd',
  venue: 'venue1',
  location: 'location1',
}, {
  date: '3rd',
  venue: 'venue2',
  location: 'location2',
}, {
  date: '4th',
  venue: 'venue3',
  location: 'location3',
}];

const venueItemBlueprint = document.querySelector('li.targets');
const venueList = venueItemBlueprint && venueItemBlueprint.parentElement;

if (venueList) {
  venueList.innerHTML = '';

  allData.forEach(venueData => {
    const venueItem = venueItemBlueprint.cloneNode();

    venueItem.innerHTML = `
      <h5>DATE</h5>
      <h4>${ venueData.date }</h4>
      <h5>VENUE</h5>
      <h4>${ venueData.venue }</h4>
      <h5>LOCATION</h5>
      <h4>${ venueData.location }</h4>
      <Button>BUY TICKETS</Button>`;

    venueList.appendChild(venueItem);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="targets"></li>
</ul>
```